# How many elements can be held in a B-tree of order n?

Tags: b-tree

Is it 2n?  Just checking.

Comment: Where are all of you taking courses that are asking you questions about b-trees? It's been b-tree week here.

Comment: San Jose State.  I'm not getting many good answers on b-trees here either.

Comment: There is no limit. Question is meaningless. Or did you have some maximum depth in mind?

Answer (score 13):

**Terminology**
The ***Order*** of a B-Tree is inconstantly defined in the literature.
(see for example the [terminology section of Wikipedia's article on B-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btree#Terminology))
Some authors consider it to be the *minimum* number of *keys* a non-leaf node may hold, while others consider it to be the *maximum* number of *children nodes* a non-leaf node may hold (which is one more than the maximum number of keys such a node could hold).
Yet many others skirt around the ambiguity by assuming a fixed length key (and fixed sized nodes), which makes the minimum and maximum the same, hence the two definitions of the order produce values that differ by 1 (as said the number of keys is always one less than the number of children.)

I define ***depth*** as the number of nodes found in the search path to a leaf record, and inclusive of the root node and the leaf node.  In that sense, a very shallow tree with only a root node pointing directly to leaf nodes has depth 2. If that tree were to grow and require an intermediate level of non-leaf nodes, its depth would be 3 etc.

**How many elements can be held in a B-Tree of order n?**
Assuming fixed length keys, and assuming that "order" n is defined as the maximum number of *child nodes*, the answer is:

```
   (Average Number of elements that fit in one Leaf-node) * n ^ (depth - 1)
```

How do I figure?...:
    The data (the "elements") is only held in leaf nodes.  So the number of element held is the average number of elements that fit in one node, times the number of leaf nodes.
    The number of leaf nodes is itself driven by the number of children that fit in a non-leaf node (the order).  For example the non-leaf node just above a leaf node, points to n (the order) leaf-nodes.  Then, the non-leaf node above this non-leaf node points to n similar nodes etc,  hence "to the power of (depth -1)".

Note that the formula above generally holds using the averages (of key held in a non-leaf node, and of elements held in a leaf node) rather than assuming fixed key length and fixed record length: trees will typically have a node size that is commensurate with the key and record sizes, hence holding a number key or records that is big enough that the effective number of keys or record held in any leaf will vary relatively little compared with the average.

**Example**:
A tree of **depth 4**  (a root node, two level of non-leaf nodes and one level [obviously] of leaf nodes) and of **order 12** (non-leaf nodes can hold up to 11 keys, hence point to 12 nodes below them) and such that **leaf nodes can contain 5 element each**, would:
    - have its root node point to 12 nodes below it   
    - each node below it points to 12 nodes below them  (hence there will be 12 * 12 nodes in the layer "3"  (assuming the root is layer 1 etc., this numbering btw is also ambiguously defined...)   
    - each node in "layer 3" will point to 12 leaf-nodes (hence  there will be 12 * 12 * 12 leaf nodes.
   - each leaf node has 5 elements (in this example case)
Hence.. such a tree will hold...

```
  Nb Of Elements in said tree = 5 * 12 * 12 * 12
                              = 5 * (12 ^ 3)
                              = 5 * (12 ^ depth -1)
                              = 8640
```

Recognize the formula on the 3rd line.

What is generally remarkable for B-Tree, and which makes for their popularity is that a relatively shallow tree (one with a limited number of "hops" between the root and the sought record), can hold a relatively high number record.  This number is ***multiplied*** by the order at each level.

Comment: This is only the # of elements in the bottom level of the tree, you also need to add the # for the levels above.

Comment: @TimK: not if the data elements are only held in leaf nodes, as stated.

Answer (score 3):

My book says that the order of a B-tree is the maximum number of pointers that can be stored in a node. (p. 348)  The number of "keys" is one less than the order. So a B-tree of order n can hold n-1 elements.

The book is "File Structures", second edition, by Michael  J. Folk.

Comment: @Phenom: the definition in your book is _one_ of the several definitions of the tree order. The various definitions can lead to confusion, but what really matters is to understand how the order AND the depth of the tree can be used to estimate the number of elements (records) that the tree can hold (as a minimum, maximum etc.)  You can refer to my answer to see how this is done.  BTW, your book's definition of _order_, is that generally attributed to D Knuth and that is the one I used for the formula.

Answer (score 0):

If your formula for the number of elements doesn't include an exponentiation somewhere, you've done it wrong.

A binary tree of order 5 can hold 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 elements, so 31 .. (which is 2^order - 1).

Edit:
I appear to have gotten order and depth / length mixed up. What on earth is the order of a binary tree? You appear to discuss B-trees as if they don't, by the very nature of their definition, hold a maximum of two child elements per element.

Comment: The B-trees in my book hold several elements in a node.  A node can have more than two child nodes.  For example, a node that can hold three elements can have four child nodes.

It's not like a binary tree where each node has only one element and two pointers for the child nodes.

Comment: @puppy, you have confused the binary trees with B-tree. There are two different data structures :) Your answer applies for binary trees not for B-trees

Answer (score 0):

Let Order of b-tree is 'm' means maximum number of nodes that can be inserted at same level in a b-tree=m-1.After that  nodes will splits.
for ex: if order is 3 then only 2 maximum node can be inserted on arrival of 3rd element ,nodes will splits by following the property of binary search tree or self balancing tree.