# Finding the height of the B-Tree of a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, primary-key, b-tree, b-tree-index

Since database data is organized in 8k pages in a B-tree, and likewise for PK information information, it should be possible for each table in the database to calculate the height of the B-Tree. Thus revealing how many jumps it takes to reach certain data.

Since both row size and PK size is of great importance, it is difficult to calculate since eg  `varchar(250)` need not take up 250 bytes.

1) Is there a way to get the info out of SQL Server?
2) if not, is it possible to give a rough estimate using some code analyzing the tables of the db?

Comment: Do you even need to know the height? Isn't random access in a B-tree structure roughly *`O(log n)`* regardless?

Comment: Well, I've seen examples of really big primary keys..  such as 2 x GUID + 2 int. It would be interesting to see the penalty as so many fewer keys can be stored in each index page

Comment: Keep in mind that only tables with clustered indexes are stored as B-trees, if there is no clustered index then the table is stored as a heap.  So what you really want to know is what is the height of the B-tree for the clustered index, thus the answer below for dm_db_index_physical_stats.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**YES! Of course!**

Check out the [DMV = dynamic management views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx) in SQL Server - they contain a treasure trove of information about your indices. The [`dm_db_index_physical_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917.aspx) is particularly useful for looking at index properties...

If you run this query in AdventureWorks against the largest table - `Sales.SalesOrderDetails` with over 200'000 rows - you'll get some data:

```
SELECT 
    index_depth,
    index_level,
    record_count,
    avg_page_space_used_in_percent,
    min_record_size_in_bytes,
    max_record_size_in_bytes,
    avg_record_size_in_bytes
FROM
    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('Sales.SalesOrderDetail'), 1, NULL, 'DETAILED')
```

You'll get output for all index levels - so you'll see at one glance how many levels there are in the index (I have three rows -> three levels in the index). Index Level 0 is always the leaf level - where in the clustered index (index_id = 1) you have your actual data pages.

[image]

You can see the average, minimum and maximum record sizes in byte and a great deal of additional info - read up on DMV's, there's a great way to diagnose and peek into the inner workings of SQL Server!

Comment: can you please advice what is order size of this B Tree index? And how SQL server determines what order size to use? It's just from curiosity point of view.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
SELECT INDEXPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('table_name'), 'index_name', 'IndexDepth')
```

Answer (score 0):

from [How many elements can be held in a B-tree of order n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572191/how-many-elements-can-be-held-in-a-b-tree-of-order-n)

```
 (Average Number of elements that fit in one Leaf-node) * n ^ (depth - 1)
```